# Searching and match count for phrase with Solr

Tags: search, solr, phrase

I am using Solr to index documents and now I need to search those documents for an exact phrase and sort the results by the number of times this phrase appears on the document. I also have to present the number of times the phrase is matched back to the user.

I was using the following query (here I am searching by the word SAP):

```
{
    :params => {
            :wt => "json",
        :indent => "on",
          :rows => 100,
         :start => 0,
             :q => "((content:SAP) AND (doc_type:ClientContact) AND (environment:production))",
          :sort => "termfreq(content,SAP) desc",
            :fl => "id,termfreq(content,SAP)"
    }
}
```

Of course this is a representation of the actual query, that is done by transforming this hash into a query string at runtime.

I managed to get the search working by using `content:"the query here"` instead of `content:the query here`, but the hard part is returning and sorting by the `termfreq`.

Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Obs: I am using Ruby but this is a legacy application and I can't use any RubyGems, I am using the HTTP interface to Solr here.

Comment: Just a comment that you should consider using fq parameters for non-text search fields like doc_type and environment. fq parameters are not used in the scoring of a search.

Comment: Thanks @dwhelan, I surely will.

Comment: Hey @tasmaniski I just researched a little more and found the ShingleFilter. It worked perfectly as show below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make it work adding a **ShingleFilter** to my `schema.xml`:

In my case I started using SunSpot, so I just had to make the following change:

```
<!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- This is the line I added -->
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

After doing that change, restarting Solr and reindexing, I was able to use `termfreq(content, "the query here")` both on my query (`q=`), on the returning fields (`fl=`) and even on sorting (`sort=`).

Answer (score 0):

put `debug=results` at the end of solr url
it will give you the phrase freq also.